# sql server left join with filter - sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables . One of employees and other breaks. I want to show all records from the Employees table ( LEFT JOIN) and see if any employee rests next Sunday (if have a record in the other table - breaks

```
SELECT  T1.idEmp
      , T1.fname
      , T1.lname
      , T1.number
      , T2.idGuard
      , T2.date 
    FROM 
        tblEmp AS T1 LEFT JOIN tblEmpGuard AS T2 
    ON 
        T1.idEmp = T2.idEmp 
    WHERE 
        date = @date
```

this just shows me employees having break next Sunday , but not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT  T1.idEmp
      , T1.fname
      , T1.lname
      , T1.number
      , T2.idGuard
      , T2.[date] 
    FROM tblEmp AS T1 
    LEFT JOIN tblEmpGuard AS T2 
    ON   T1.idEmp = T2.idEmp  
    AND  T2.[date] = @date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the where clause is filtering for employees with a break on that date. This occurs after the join thus excluding employees without dates. Moving this criteria to the on clause will solve the problem.

```
SELECT T1.idEmp, T1.fname, T1.lname, T1.number, T2.idGuard, T2.date 
FROM tblEmp AS T1 
LEFT JOIN tblEmpGuard AS T2 
ON T1.idEmp = T2.idEmp 
AND T2.date = @date
```